# Как отловить fatal signal 11 из нативной библиотеки?

Tags: android, native, vlc

Приложение использует стороннюю нативную библиотеку libvlc. Обычные неотловленные исключения отлавливаются с помощью своей реализации UncaughtExceptionHandler. Но кроме того, иногда приложение просто прекращает работу, в логах fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV). Как отловить эту ошибку. Пусть приложение завершается, но чтобы пользователю было ясно что ошибка именно эта. Переписывать нативную библиотеку не вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете установить обработчик для интересующего вас сигнала:

```
void sigsegv_handler(int signum) {
    // Тут что-то делаем.
    signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    exit(3);
}
signal(SIGSEGV, sigsegv_handler);
```

Но, по большому счёту, это вам ничего не даст, кроме возможности записать в лог или что-то в таком духе, поскольку ваше приложение всё равно упадёт. Есть, конечно, хитрые способы проигнорировать SIGSEGV, но всё это очень плохо без чёткого понимания, что вы и зачем делаете. В противном случае получите UB.

Вообще, лучший вариант в вашем случае - всё же разобраться с причиной проблемы (даже если очень хочется этого избежать) и исправить её. Всё остальное - UB и недовольные пользователи.